# When I try to commit the SVN, it shows a conflict with the image files, but I don't see any conflicts when I check locally. How can I resolve this?

Tags: ios, svn, cornerstone

My project is an iOS project.
When I commit the code to SVN, I see a 'D' next to my image files, indicating deletion.
However, when I try to commit the code, a conflict message pops up for the image folder, even though I don't see any conflicts locally.
Why is this happening? I am using CornerStone software.
[image: Here is popView]

Comment: I can see a lot of funny orange boxes with exclamation marks in them in your screenshot. Now I don't know Cornerstone but could it be that these indicate conflicts? Probably it's just a [tree conflict](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.treeconflicts.html).

Comment: It is a tree conflict,I delete the local image files and revert to old version, do a update, then i fixed problem,maybe it is a application bug.

Comment: Did you mean to delete those images or did it just happen? I have to admit I don't fully understand what you were trying to do. With the little information I have, this may as well be Subversion working as intended.

Comment: If it's fixed, consider posting an answer so future readers can benefit from your solution.

Comment: the situation is, I can't find any conflicts in my local files, so I revert the file which the pop view has mentioned to last commit version, then clicked update button, the bug finally fixed.I consumed that is a application bug.